# In "random" time when execute "./airflow.sh dags reserialize" occurs error like "duplicate key value violates unique constraint serialized_dag_pkey'"

Tags: python, airflow, workflow, airflow-2.x

I have a file in python that generate dynamic DAG in [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org), and sometime when have a new code in that file, is necessary to execute `./airflow.sh dags reserialize`, but sometimes this command return with an error like below, but :

```
[2023-04-13 19:46:54,669] {dag.py:2690} INFO - Sync 35 DAGs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 39, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 52, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 75, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 108, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/dag_command.py", line 492, in dag_reserialize
    dagbag.sync_to_db(session=session)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 72, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 645, in sync_to_db
    for attempt in run_with_db_retries(logger=self.log):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 384, in __iter__
    do = self.iter(retry_state=retry_state)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 351, in iter
    return fut.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 428, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 660, in sync_to_db
    self.dags.values(), processor_subdir=processor_subdir, session=session
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 72, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 2701, in bulk_write_to_db
    orm_dags: list[DagModel] = with_row_locks(query, of=DagModel, session=session).all()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2773, in all
    return self._iter().all()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2919, in _iter
    execution_options={"_sa_orm_load_options": self.load_options},
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1713, in execute
    conn = self._connection_for_bind(bind)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1553, in _connection_for_bind              2-tetris-linkedin-hourly-days', 'fileloc': '/opt/airflow/dags/register_dynamic_dag.py', 'fileloc_hash': 51105027638417678, 'data': '{"__version": 1, "dag": {"_dag_id": "96ddcc3b-900a-44a7-bda9-81b9eeserialized DAG: /opt/airflow/dags/register_alerts_resport_dag.py
    engine, execution_options       python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 631, in _serialize_dag_capturing_errors
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 721, in _connection_for_bind
    self._assert_active()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 608, in _assert_active
    code="7s2a",
sqlalchemy.exc.PendingRollbackError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: (psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "serialized_dag_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (dag_id)=(96ddcc3b-900a-44a7-bda9-81b9eefde4d2-dynamic-dag-hourly-days) already exists.
```

Code of `airflow.sh` below

```
PROJECT_DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"

set -euo pipefail

export COMPOSE_FILE="${PROJECT_DIR}/docker/docker-compose.dev.yml"
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    exec docker-compose --project-directory=./ run --rm airflow-cli "${@}"
else
    exec docker-compose --project-directory=./ run --rm airflow-cli
fi
```

This file is is provided by the [airflow's documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html) and I'm using docker-compose.

The python's file that register dynamic dag (I shortened code to focus on the problem):

```py
# ... imports

def create_dynamic_dag(dag_id, company):
    schedule_interval = "* 5 * * * *"
    local_tz = pytz.timezone(company['timezone']['id'])
    start_date = datetime.now(local_tz) - timedelta(days=7, hours=0)

    @dag(
        dag_id=dag_id,
        schedule=schedule_interval,
        start_date=start_date,
        catchup=False,
        max_active_runs=1,
    )
    def dynamic_dag():
        @task.branch
        def ping():
            # ...code to ping
            # return 'done' or 'notify_error'

        @task
        def notify_error():
            # ...code to notify error

        @task
        def done():
            # ... code to done
        
        ping_instance = ping()

        notify_error_instance = notify_error()
        done_instance = done()

        ping_instance >> [done_instance, notify_error_instance]
    
    dagD = dynamic_dag()

    globals()[dag_id] = dagD

    return dagD

for company in data['companies']:
    for connection in company['connections']:
        configConnection = next(filter(lambda c: connection['type'] in c['type'], data_map['connections']), None)
        for typeRoutine in configConnection['routines']:
            dag_id = f"{company['id']}-{company['slug']}-{configConnection['name']}-{typeRoutine['type']}"
            dagD = create_dynamic_dag(dag_id, company, typeRoutine, configConnection)
```